# Getting a list of subdirectories 3 levels down

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a department folder/client folder/matter folder.  Just need those folders in the entire directory. Is this possible without listing the files? Even if it listed the files within those 3 levels would be fine but not go beyond that.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to list all matters for a single client, or a hierarchical display of departments, clients, and matters, but only the names of folders at each level?

Comment: Ex. I have a directory that contains folders like this Corporate\099999\00001\*.* I only need the first 3 items in a list and not the content within the 3rd folder whether files or folders.

Answer (score 0):

`dir \department\client\matter\*.* /AD` will list only the folders that are in the `matter` folder.